# How to create a batch file to ftp files in the directory with the name realated to yesterday?

Tags: filesystems, batch, ftp, batch-file, csv

I have a set of directories with encoded in their names the date.
Inside those directories there are files named `files.csv`.

The directories have a standard name as, for example,

> /opt/oss/server/var/fileint/pm/pmexport_20150915

where the name of the last directory changes with the day, e.g   `pmexport_20150915` is the directory of 15 September 2015.

I would like to create a batch file to ftp automatically the `files.csv` of the previous day to a fixed destination.
For example today is the 16 of September 2015: I want to ftp `files.csv` from directory of yesterday, `pmexport_20150915`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I seem to have undermined your comment sorry... I'll leave the answer as I haven't wrote the code just pointed to a nearly there example with some pointers of how to complete it

Comment: @JoeTaylor Not a problem. We just like people to make some effort ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Looks like he's using a non windows machine anyway by the filepath. Doubt powershell would help at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://msexchange.me/2014/03/05/upload-files-to-ftp-server/) post about uploading files with Powershell?

```
    ##################################################################################### 
##           Script will Upload files to FTP    
##           Author:  Vikas Sukhija                                                            
##                                                                     
##           Date: 02-24-2013 
##           Modified Date:- 02-26-2013 (included loging & monitoring) 
##################################################################################### 
#############################Define Log Files######################################## 

$date = get-date -format d 
$date = $date.ToString().Replace(“/”, “-”) 
$time = get-date -format t 
$month = get-date  
$month1 = $month.month 
$year1 = $month.year 
$time = $time.ToString().Replace(":", "-") 
$time = $time.ToString().Replace(" ", "") 

$log1 = ".\Logs" + "\" + "FTP_" + $date + "_.log" 
$log2 = ".\Logs" + "\" + "FTP_" + $month1 +"_" + $year1 +"_.log" 
$log3 = ".\Logs" + "\" + "FTP_" + $date + $time + "_.log" 

$logs = ".\Logs" + "\" + "Powershell" + $date + "_" + $time + "_.txt" 

#Start-Transcript -Path $logs  
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Script Started" 

###########################Variables###################################### 

$smtpServer = "smtp.lab.com" # Change  
$fromadd = "DoNotReplyftp@lab.com" # Change  
$email1 = "Vikas.Sukhija@lab.com"  # Change  
$ftp = "ftp://127.0.0.1/" # Change 
$user = "vikas"  # Change 
$pass = "password" # Change 
$uploadfpath = "C:\Uploadftp\ftpfiles" # Define the Folder from where files will be uploaded  

########################################################################### 

$checkitems = Get-ChildItem $uploadfpath 
$countitems = $checkitems.count 
if ($countitems -eq 0) 
{ 
Write-Host "No items to process" -ForegroundColor Green 
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : No items to process, script will exit" 
exit 
} 
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Total number of items to process $countitems" 

$processed = ".\processed\$date" + "-" + $time 
if((test-path $processed) -like $false) 
{ 
New-Item -Path "$processed" -type directory 
} 

##################################################################################### 

if ($error -ne $null) 
      { 
#SMTP Relay address 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 

#Mail sender 
$msg.From = $fromadd 
#mail recipient 
$msg.To.Add($email1) 
$msg.Subject = "FTP Script error" 
$msg.Body = $error 
$smtp.Send($msg) 
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Script Terminated because of error: $error" 
$error.clear() 
exit 

       } 
  else 

      { 
    Write-host "no errors till now" 
      } 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient  

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)   

#Upload each file in upload directory... 

foreach($item in (dir $uploadfpath "*.*")){  
    Write-host  "Uploading $item..."  -ForegroundColor Green 
    $dt = Get-Date 
    Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name)  
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
      if($error -ne $null) 
        { 
    Write-Host "Items will not be moved" -ForegroundColor Red 
        } 
        else 
        { 
    Write-Host "Moving $item to processed" -ForegroundColor green 
    Move-Item "$uploadfpath\$item" $processed 
    $dt = Get-Date 
    Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Moving $item to processed" 
        } 
 }  

if ($error -ne $null) 
      { 
#SMTP Relay address 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 

#Mail sender 
$msg.From = $fromadd 
#mail recipient 
$msg.To.Add($email1) 
$msg.Subject = "FTP Script error" 
$msg.Body = $error 
$smtp.Send($msg) 
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Script encountered error: $error" 
$error.clear() 
       } 
  else 

      { 
    Write-host "no errors till now" 
      } 
$dt = Get-Date 
Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Script Processing finished" 

#Stop-Transcript 
##################################################################
```

All you need to create is a string that holds the files you want to update. If you use the Get-Date function in this way:
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Then you will be able to create a string array containing your files you want to upload. You should be able to do this by modifying the get-childitem to include a filter on the string.
I can't fully compile this and test it for you as I have no FTP to check it with and limited tome but hopefully with a quick tweak you will have it working fine.

Comment: Dear , please your support to create a simple batch file to get and well display yesterday date

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you want to take the files **from a Linux machine**.
The steps you have to do are the same if you have to program a bash shell or a powershell, only the language is different... seldom in a language there is not the word (command) you need and you have to use others.

I will not give you a full working solution, I will use `scp` that makes a secure copy (it's a remote file copy program). Take it as hints and some command you can find useful (do `man date` for the help of `date`...).

```
#!/bin/bash
DestinationPath="/tmp"    # Here you have to put where you want to copy the file
FileToTake='files.csv'    # Here the file you want to take
PathFrom=$(date -d yesterday "+/opt/oss/server/var/fileint/pm/pmexport_%Y%m%d")
FullFileNameToTake="${PathFrom}/${FileToTake}"
scp -p user@host:"$FullFileNameToTake" "$DestinationPath"
```

if you want to use `ftp` you can merge what above with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894435/3569208).

Comment: Dear ALL please your support  to create a simple batch file to get and well display yesterday date